# jQuery Jump Menu Functionality For iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

On my page I have a regular list of links.

I found a script that will convert that to a select box and options that replicate the links.

Using the select box, and selecting one of the 3 options jumps to that options value/url.

But, it does not work on my iPhone. Does anyone know how I could adjust this to work on iPhone/mobile?

http://tinyurl.com/8a52uav

Thank you for any help. I am not good with jQuery at all really :(